# Mongodb "getting" keys to update values within them

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document for a user

```
bob = collection.find_one({'username':'bob'})
```

This returns to me a python dictionary,

```
print bob
>>{u'_id': ObjectId('542130bd43941e7878a8fa378'),
   u'likes': {},
}
type(bob)
>> dict
```

So how can I do something like `bob.update({'likes': {'sports':'football','movie':'terminator'}})`

Comment: Is there any problem with this: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `update()` incorrectly. `update()` updates a document within a collection. So you must call it on your collection, and pass it a dictionary that specifies the document you wish to update, and use the `$set` modifier to modify certain fields in the document you specified earlier.

Like this:

`collection.update({'username': 'bob'}, {'$set': {'likes': {'sports': 'football', 'movie': 'terminator'}}})`

Check out the documents here for more useful information regarding `update()`, as Salvador Dali already mentioned:

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update